# How do I use Font Awesome 5 with emacs after changing the default font of emacs?

Tags: emacs

Whenever I open a file which contains font awesome 5 icons in it, or I paste a icon into emacs buffer, emacs will freeze forever.

After researching for an afternoon, I found that as long as I don't customize emacs default font (by putting `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "NovaMono-12"))` in my emacs config file), it will work fine.

Alse, using emacs with `-nw` flag can display the icons normally too.